# Ionic framework redirect to home on start

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, router

I'm building a mobile app with ionic, I'm facing a strange problem ..
If I reload the page ( F5 ) from, let say "/tabs/connected/channel/edit" I'm always redirected to "/tabs/home" ( after the state resolving ).

PS : The resolve phase is correclty executed and I never reject it. And then on promise resolving I'm always redirected to /tabs/home.

Here is my config block :

> ```
> .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
> ```

```
    var userResolve = function(user, $q, $auth) {

        if (!$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            return $q.resolve();
        }
        if (user.loaded) {
            return $q.resolve();
        }
        return user.blockingRefresh();
    };

    // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
    // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
    // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
    $stateProvider

    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
        .state('tabs', {
            url: '/tabs',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
        })
        .state('tabs.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'home-tab': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                    controller: ''
                }
            }
        })
        .state('tabs.account', {
            url: '/account',
            views: {
                'account-tab': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/account/account.html',
                    controller: 'AccountController'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                userData: userResolve
            }
        })
        .state('tabs.login', {
            url: '/account/login',
            views: {
                'account-tab': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/account/login.html',
                    controller: 'AccountController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('tabs.register', {
            url: '/account/register',
            views: {
                'account-tab': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/account/register.html',
                    controller: 'RegisterController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('tabs.connected', {
            url: '/connected',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'account-tab': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/connected.html"
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                userData: userResolve
            }
        })
        .state('tabs.connected.channel-create', {
            url: '/channel/create',
            templateUrl: 'templates/channel/create.html',
            controller: 'CreateChannelController'
        })
        .state('tabs.connected.channel-edit', {
            url: '/channel/edit',
            templateUrl: 'templates/channel/edit.html',
            controller: 'EditChannelController'
        });



    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tabs/account');

})
```

Here is tabs.html :

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-assertive tabs-icon-top">

<ion-tab title="Home" ui-sref="tabs.home" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
    <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="Account" ui-sref="tabs.account" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline">
    <ion-nav-view name="account-tab"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

I must precise that I never use $state.go('/tabs/home') I'm my code at all. I'm sure of that.
My goal is to stay on the same route even if I reload the app. ( This problem does not occurs on some state and I don't know why because they doesn't do anything different than the problematic ones .. )

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I also got this type of error in Angular Ui-Router.

Below solution is work for me.

Just change it too

```
    .state('tabs.connected.channelcreate', {
        url: '/channelcreate',
        templateUrl: 'templates/channel/create.html',
        controller: 'CreateChannelController'
    })
```

url should be

```
    "/tabs/connected/channeledit"
```

And it will work.

Comment: Thank you, but I doesn't work ... I have this : 

`            .state('tabs.connected.channelcreate', {
                url: '/channelcreate',
                templateUrl: 'templates/channel/create.html',
                controller: 'CreateChannelController'
            })
            .state('tabs.connected.channeledit', {
                url: '/channeledit',
                templateUrl: 'templates/channel/edit.html',
                controller: 'EditChannelController'
            });`

Comment: @NathanVss : Can you post **templates/tabs.html** code snippet so I can take look and help you.

Comment: Try this which I modified. Hope this will help you - [codepen](http://codepen.io/nirmal25/pen/EKKmxe)